# Not properly announced homework assignment

Tags: homework

I skipped my last homework assignment due to the fact that it was not properly announced by Professor at the and of the class. I am not experienced in writing this kind of letters and have no clue how to request an opportunity to submit my homework.

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The wording for the letter will strongly depend on the country you are working in. Could you please indicate that?

Comment: I am working in USA. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Would you care to give a little more details about "_it was not properly announced by Professor at the and of the class_"?

Comment: Usually, at the end of each class the Professor announces which is going to be the next homework assignment. This time, he didn't do so.

Comment: You are in college - you have to take responsibility for your actions and education. Be proactive.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience in the USA, the deadlines for the homeworks were possibly in the syllabus / in the online course management system, and the professor was not obliged to announce them at the end of the class. Your experience, however, might be different.

In any way, I would simply write a short note explaining that you failed to submit the homework on time, and asking for an extension / for the possibility to submit the homework. If technically possible, most professors will agree to do that.

Do not: blame the professor for not having announced the assignment. That won't take you far.